# How to pass parameter to function Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have function:

```
 public static function profile(Request $request){

        return self::getProfileType(Request $request);
    }
```

How to use function without: `Request $request`:

```
public static function profile(){
    return self::getProfileType(Request $request);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global helper

```
public static function profile(){
    return self::getProfileType(request()); // request() is a global function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you declare an object type you need to pass that type for the param, but if you replicate this, you should not inform the type, for ex:

```
public static function profile(Request $request)
{
    return self::getProfileType($request);
}
```

but if you don't want to specify a type, just remove `Request` before `$request`

```
public static function profile($request)
{
    return self::getProfileType($request);
}
```

then you can pass any value to this param and it'll not thow an error

Comment: Yes, but how I can use this without  `Request $request` in parent function? Only inside?

Comment: Problem is when I call this library method from templete blade: `{{\App\Helpers\Profile::getProfileType(Request $request)}}` It does not work

Comment: for this particular case, Laravel provide access to request values without passing via param `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()`

Comment: I tried  this: `{{\App\Helpers\Profile::profile(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all())}}` in function `profile()` I get this as empty array

Comment: do you have any post or get data?

Comment: What is it mean?